# How do I treat / maintain IKEA Platta wood patio tiles?

Tags: wood, deck, tile

Over a year ago we put a good sized set of [IKEA Platta deck tiles](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/20165486) on our patio. After exposure to the elements, they are now dis-coloring and becoming a bit 'rough'.

What exactly do I need to do to get them back into shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These tiles are made of Acacia wood, which is OK for outdoor use, but must be re-oiled every year.

Here is my suggestion for yearly maintenance:

- To smooth out the roughness, hand sand with a high grit sandpaper (I would avoid using a power sander)
- Thoroughly clean the area using a stiff bristle brush and water, with a small amount of a mild detergent soap
- Allow the deck to dry completely
- Apply a light coat of tung oil with a paintbrush, wait 30 minutes, and wipe the excess off with a clean cloth.

Answer (score 1):

All wood will discolor in time with exposure to the sun's UV rays.

Any reason you're not just following the instructions on the [product page you linked to](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/20165486)?

> **Care instructions**
>
> *Treat the floor decking with oil at regular intervals
>   in order to protect and retain the
>   wood.* Note! Make sure that it is clean
>   and dry before being re-oiled.
>   Location: Outdoors. Can be left
>   outdoors all summer.

[Not tyring to be difficult, but since you didn't mention the instructions there, I figured you may have missed them.]

Comment: Hello, I'm the type of person most comfortable in-front of a keyboard, mouse, and glowing panel/tube. As such, I'm not experienced in hte maintainance of things kept outside and wanted to be sure there weren't basic assumptions of its care that I'm unaware of.

Comment: @mummey, no problem at all. No offense intended. @James Van Huis's answer seems pretty reasonable to me so I'd go with that.